# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maximum' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button id="max" onclick="Application(document).maximum();">Maximum</button>
```

While calling `maximum` I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maximum' of undefined

```
function Application(document) {
this.maximum=function () {
    document.getElementById("result-value").innerHTML=new StatisticsCalculator().maximum([1,2]);
   }
 }
```

I included both(`Application,StatisticsCalculator)` js files html file.Still getting the problem.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Include `new` `onclick="new Application(document).maximum();`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to run a function on the click event?

Comment: You need to use `new` to create an object with a constructor. This looks like a completely meaningless pattern, though, and you should probably make `maximum` a plain old function (not on an object) instead. Then you can attack it using `addEventListener` in your script instead of using the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `new` before `Application()` call

```html
<script>
  function Application(args) {
    this.maximum = function() {
      console.log(args)
    }
  }
</script>
<button id="max" onclick="new Application('maximum called').maximum();">Maximum</button>
```

alternatively

```html
<script>
  function Application(args) {
    this.maximum = function(args) {
      console.log(args)
    }
  }
  
  var app = new Application();
</script>
<button id="max" onclick="app.maximum('maximum called');">Maximum</button>
```

Comment: I gave this a thumbs up.. don't know why the thumbs down was necessary..